# Install shield leaving files after uninstall

Tags: installshield, uac, virtualstore

I've created an Install shield 2009 installation which installs a number of files to C:\Program Files. When running on Windows 7 the installation works perfectly. However, when an uninstall is performed the files are removed from C:\Program Files BUT are not removed from the VirtualStore automatically. Is there a way to do this without having to delete the files manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are created by the installer than it should remove them, to see why they don't get removed I recommend creating a [verbose log](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300). If the files are created by the application, after the installation, then you will need to remove them manually.